# How to transfer SQL Group by results to a Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, mysql, pandas

I have sql query that return a data set in following format

```
user_id, type_id, avg
1, 3, 2.5
1, 2, 3.0
1, 5, 4.6
1, 11, 3.4
2, 2, 4.5
2, 3, 3.0
2, 11, 3.1
```

data above comes from following query, and it get executed is a very large table.

```
select u.user_id, t.type_id, sum(u.preference)/count(u.preference) 
from user_preference u, item_type_pairs t 
where t.item_id = u.item_id group by u.user_id, t.type_id;
```

Query takes 10min and returns **2 plus million records**. My end goal is to put this in  data frame where rows are `user_id` and columns representing `type_id` and each cell representing the `avg` value for an item by `type_id`.

```
   type_id_1, type_id_2, type_id_3
u1|             3.0        2.5
u2|             4.5        3.0
```

What would be the best way to go about on this. I am also still figuring out? Should I be reading row by row and somehow populate the data frame?

Comment: Can you fill in the DataFrame completely? It's not clear (to me) exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: Is your problem that you can't read the sql output into python? Or that you don't know how to do the group by in pandas? Please edit your question to clarify.

Comment: @unutbu Sorry I made a mistake in original data frame representation. now its updated. Does it make more sense?

Comment: @Wilduck Assume that I have connected to the database and has this results set using mysql cursor. I want to populate the pandas dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume that you are able to create a MySql connection object, using something like:

```
import MySQLdb as mdb

con = mdb.connect('localhost', 'testuser', 'test623', 'testdb')
```

Then, getting your data into python is as simple as:

```
with con:
    cur = con.cursor(mdb.cursors.DictCursor)
    cur.execute(
        "select u.user_id, t.type_id, sum(u.preference)/count(u.preference)"
        "from user_preference u, item_type_pairs t"
        "where t.item_id = u.item_id group by u.user_id, t.type_id;"
    )
    rows = cur.fetchall()
```

At this point `rows` will look something like:

```
[{'user_id': 1, 'type_id': 2, 'avg': 2.5},
 {'user_id': 1, 'type_id': 2, 'avg': 3.0},
 ...]
```

From this step, creating a pandas dataframe from this data is extremely simple:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

my_df = pd.DataFrame(rows)
```

Then, you can use the `pivot_table` function to transform it into your desired output:

```
final_df = pd.pivot_table(
    df,
    index='user_id',
    columns='type_id',
    values='avg',
    agg_func=np.average
)
```

Comment: Is it ok to use `fetchall` with 2 million records?